# JMH: What does the score value mean?

Tags: jmh

I don't understand the score attribute from the JMH results? I don't find anything on the web about it, too.

Can anyone tell me, what it is about? As far as I understand is a higher score better than a lower, but what does it exactly mean and how is it calculated?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

JMH supports the following Benchmark [modes](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/6cc1450c6a0f/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/annotations/Mode.java):

- Throughput: operations per unit of time
- AverageTime: average time per operation
- SampleTime: samples the time for each operation
- SingleShotTime: measures the time for a single operation

Now you can analyse if higher score is better or not.

The default benchmark mode is (Throughput) [1](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/6cc1450c6a0f/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/annotations/Mode.java) and in this case higher value is better.

If you are interested how exactly each benchmark result is calculated check [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/6cc1450c6a0f/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/results).